# Best way to display a list within a json object via Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend

im trying to display the objects within a list within a json object via angular, but i can't really get it to work.

The json is delivered via a service as a resolved Promise:

```
getJson(): Promise<any> {
    return Promise.resolve(this.testdata);
}
```

Thus function returns an `[object Promise]`

The testdata json string is of structure:

```
{"errorCode":"ok",
 "objList":[{},{},etc.]
}
```

What i want is to display a list (for example with ngFor) and have access to the properties of the objects within the objList.

**My initial idea** was to just iterate over the object list with ngFor, to do this i created the following class

```
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

json : {"objList": []}

constructor(
    private router: Router,
    public app: AppService,
    public pService: pService
) {
}

ngOnInit(){
    this.json = this.pService.getJson()
  }
}
```

This does not work however, as im getting the error that property `objList` is missing in type `Promise<any>`.

I also tried ngFor with KeyValue pipe, however it also didnt work properly.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: It's a promise, so either use async/await or just do `this.pService.getJson().then(data => this.data = data);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try this code snipped

```
    ngOnInit(){
    this.pService.getJson().
     then(response => {
       this.json = response;
     })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that `this.pService.getJson()` returns a `Promise` reference. To learn more about `Promise` click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

So here is the fix you need to apply:

```
ngOnInit() {
  // you will need to implement the then call of the promise
  this.pService.getJson()
    .then((result) => {
      this.json = result;
      // then call the change detection, I will explain this below
      return this.cd.detectChanges();
    });
}
```

Additionally this may cause changeDetector issues for you so you may want
to inject the `ChangeDetectorRef` in the component constructor

```
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    public app: AppService,
    public pService: Service,
    public cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
) {
}
```

This should sort you out, but i'd further advise reading more about promises
and considering using `Observable` instead of `Promise`, check this [link](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular) on `Observable`